How to make text in the container align vertically center and horizontally center
How to make text in the container align vertically center and horizontally center
without using flex and position absolute. only use text-align center and vertical align center.
in which scenario vertical align center will work.

<html>
<div class="text" style="height: 200px; border: 1px solid #ccc; text-align: center;">
  <p style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;"></p>
</div>
<div class="text">
  <p>CENTER TEXT</p>
</div>
</html>

